# In a fight why do I instantly lose

Tags: nhl-13

When I challenge someone to a fight in NHL 13 (Be A Pro), sometimes I instantly get taken to the ground. Is this because I have fought to many times in the game?

It seems like a glitch or bug to me, but the only thing I can think of is that maybe my character is exhausted, a rookie, or just weak from not having enough stats into fighting.

Comment: Well I don't play sports games, so I can't help - but to cheer you up I found a fairly hilarious NHL 13 [Hercules Checking](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2012/10/05/ea-responds-to-hilarious-nhl-13-glitch.aspx) glitch, complete with EA response.  Cheers.

Comment: I never knew about this. I wish I could up your comment 1000 times, this is great. Thanks :)

Comment: Laughing at insane physics glitches is what brings us together as gamers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't press LT & RT (Xbox 360)/R2 & L2 (PS3) at the same time. If you're not doing that, then I have no idea.